# Getting php array dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

With the following code I try to add a new div-element with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var languages = <?php echo json_encode($languages); ?>;
  var div       = '';
    $.each(languages, function (key, value) {
      div  = '<div class="main bg_notice" style="padding:3px; line-height:20px;">';
      div += '  <img src="/lang/' + value['directory'] + '/admin/images/' + value['image'] + '" alt="' + value['name'] + '" title="' + value['name'] + '" style="border:0;">';
      div += '  <b><?php echo TEXT_MASK_ALIAS; ?></b>';
      div += '  <input type="text" name="mask_alias[' + value['id'] + ']" value="" style="width:80%" maxlength="255">';
      div += '</div>';
      $('[name="categories_name[' + value['id'] + ']').closest('div').after(div);
    });
});
```

The value for the input field is created dynamically in PHP

```
echo (isset($mask_alias[$languages[$i]['id']]) ? stripslashes($mask_alias[$languages[$i]['id']]) : $categories_desc_fields['mask_alias']);
```

How do I get this into javascript writing style.

```
$languages[$i]['id']
```

is equivalent to

```
+ value['id'] +
```

in javascript.

The result should look like this non working code

```
div += '  <input type="text" name="mask_alias[' + value['id'] + ']" value="<?php echo (isset($mask_alias[$languages[$i]['id']]) ? stripslashes($mask_alias[$languages[$i]['id']]) : $categories_desc_fields['mask_alias']); ?>" style="width:80%" maxlength="255">';
```

Comment: Since you're doing this in document.ready, it's worth pointing out that you could probably do this with only php, and not have to worry about echoing php variables to be read by javascript.

Comment: It might just be me but I am really having a hard time understanding what it is you're asking for, could you elaborate?

Comment: I've added the codeline which I like to change to javascript syntax.

Comment: Post (some of) the content of `<?php echo json_encode($languages); ?>` please.

Comment: var languages is 0: Object { id: "2", name: "Deutsch", code: "de", … }
1: Object { id: "1", name: "English", code: "en", … }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do part of this in php and part of this in javascript.

I suggest that in PHP, you create a new array based on languages that will be handed to javascript, where all the php-level calculations have been already done.

For example

```
// php code
// you already have $languages defined
$jsLanguages = array_map(function ($key, $lang) {
  $lang['mask'] = isset($mask_alias[$lang['id']]) ? stripslashes($mask_alias[$lang['id']]) : $categories_desc_fields['mask_alias'];
  $lang['imageURL'] = "/lang/{$lang['directory']}/admin/images/{$lang['image']}";
  return $lang;
}, $languages);
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var languages = <?php echo json_encode($jsLanguages); ?>;
  var div       = '';
    $.each(languages, function (key, lang) {
      div  = '<div class="main bg_notice" style="padding:3px; line-height:20px;">';
      div += '  <img src="' + lang.imageURL + '" title="' + lang.name + '" style="border:0;">';
      div += '  <b><?php echo TEXT_MASK_ALIAS; ?></b>';
      div += '  <input type="text" name="mask_alias[' + lang.id + ']" value="' + lang.mask + '" style="width:80%" maxlength="255">';
      div += '</div>';
      $('[name="categories_name[' + lang.id + ']"').closest('div').after(div);
    });
});
```

Comment: The php part causes an error to another javascript loaded by the shopsystem

Comment: I always forget "use" - that change might work.  If it produces an error, what's the error?

Comment: When I use your php-code (even in the original file from the shopsystem) it causes an error TypeError: a is undefined in ckeditor.js

Comment: If I change function (key, lang) to function (lang) it seems to work

Answer (score 1):

`var languages = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($languages); ?>)'`

Comment: `var languages = <?php echo json_encode($languages); ?>;` is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `languages` is a string in json format rather than an actual object.

Try using `JSON.parse` to convert the string to an object.

`var languages = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($languages); ?>);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

> The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.